# Select an input inside an ui.item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

With jQuery UI. to select just one sortable item I find out that I can use ui.item. But I cannot find a way to select only an input inside the sortable item (only 'this', the input inside the item I move)

JQUERY UI:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    sort: function (event, ui) { // during sorting
        var move = (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left);

        if(move>100){
        //ui.item.({height:'25px'});
        }

    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sortable">
    <div> <input type="text"  value="item1"> </div>
    <div> <input type="text"  value="item2"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works too: ui.item.find('input')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use many functions...

- `ui.item.find('input')`
- `ui.item.children('input')`

If you are using children() it will return collections you can get the individuals like these

- `ui.item.children('input')[0]`
- `ui.item.children('input').first()` or `.last()`